# Modifying dictionary in one instance of a class makes same change to all other instances

Tags: python

I've discovered this wierd glitch in python. I was playing around with evolution simulations, so I made loads of creatures that each has it's own genes. As you can imagine, it's important to be able to mutate the genes and create new creatures with it. I saved each creatures genes in a dictionary, and each gene was a list within the dictionary (which might have had more lists in it).

The problem arose when trying to apply mutations to the genes. If I didn't make a copy of the gene dictionary any change to the dictionary would result in a similar change in all other creatures. (Not really a big problem, but I would be interested in hearing a reason for this. Do dictionaries and classes not play well together?)

So whats the problem? Just copy the genes, right? Well, the thing I discovered was that this problem also applied to the lists inside the dictionary. If I didn't want the changes to translate across all instances, I would have to copy the list (copyList = List[:]). This would happen even though I was making the changes to a COPY of the original f*cking gene dictionary. What's more, any list within a list would have to get the same treatment. What's even more, I still get this problem if I make the changes in a function outside the class which I call within the class.

This is quite annoying, but I think there may be other problems I am not aware of: other ways in which the genes of other instances may be corrupted. I've been having problems with my simulation because of this. Making copy after copy after copy results in messy code.

Does anybody know why this is happening? Is there a simple way to fix it? Below is some simplified code to illustrate the problem. I can't imagine what is going on.

tl;dr: Run the code below to see some wierd voodoo shit:

```
#DEMONSTRATION OF A F*CKING STUPID PHENOMENON WITH PYTHON CLASSES

class creature(object):
    def __init__(self,genes):
        self.genes = genes

    def changeGenes(self,details):
        genes = self.genes.copy()
        n,i,s = details
        try:
            genes[n][i] = s 
            self.genes = genes
            #WAY THAT WORKS
            #g = genes[n][:]
            #g[i] = s
            #genes[n] = g
            #self.genes = genes
        except:
            print('error: incorrect key or index')

def main():
    active_objects = []
    genes = {'1': [1,2,3],
             '2': [1,2,3]}
    for n in range(3):
        active_objects.append(creature(genes))

    while True:
        print('\nPlease choose what to do: ')
        print('1) Change genes of first creature')
        print('2) Print all genes')
        c = input('Your choice: ')

        if c == '1':  
            n = input('Choose gene key: ')
            i = int(input('Choose gene index: '))
            s = input('Choose symbol to replace gene: ')
            active_objects[0].changeGenes([n,i,s])
        elif c == '2':
            for item in active_objects:
                print(item.genes)
        elif c == '0':
            print('Thank you! Come again!')
            break
        else:
            print('error: invalid input')

main()
```

Answer (score 2):

This is not a glitch but intended behavior. Dictionaries are references if you pass them to a new variable, the new variable will still reference the old dictionary (this behavior comes actually in handy if you want to change some value deep in a nested dictionary). If you want to have a new dictionary that resembles the old one you have to do make a deepcopy. .copy makes a shallow copy in which nested dictionary will be still treated as references.

Just try:

```
from copy import deepcopy

class creature(object):
    def __init__(self, genes):
        self.genes = deepcopy(genes)
```

and it it will work.

On that note, passing mutable references into functions is not a good idea either. Just because they can change at any time if referenced from somewhere else. You should look into immutable data structures. The collection module has some very interesting options.

Answer (score 1):

As you noticed, when two variables point to the same instance of a mutable object (in your case, a dict or a list) then modifications on this instance will be seen by all variables pointing to it.

The "variable" can also be a dict element, or a position in a list... Assignment in python does not copy objects (this would be slow) and uses references (ie, pointers) instead. Thus the same object instance can have references pointing to it in multiple places. This is usually desirable:

```
a = MyClass()
doSomethingTo( a )
```

You would expect a to be modified if doSomethngTo() actually does something to it. This occurs because a reference to the object a is passed as a parameter to the function, not a copy of the object.

One solution is to use the [copy.deepcopy](https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html) module.

You could also replace the lists with tuples, and create a new tuple instead of modifying the list. You would still need to copy the dict, though.